# Purely inseparable $k$-rational dominant maps between an absolutely irreducible $k$-surface and $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-surfaces, birational-geometry, characteristic-p

Let $X$ be an absolutely irreducible surface over an algebraically closed or finite field $k$ of characteristic $p$. Is it true that the following conditions are equivalent?

1. There is a purely inseparable $k$-rational dominant map $\varphi\!: X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$.
2. There is a purely inseparable $k$-rational dominant map $\psi\!: \mathbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow X$, i.e., $X$ is a generalized Zariski surface.

Are degrees of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ equal?

Comment: At least if you assume that $X$ is normal, then those conditions are equivalent.  In the non-normal case, let $X$ be a surface whose seminormalization equals its normalization.  If the normalization equals $\mathbb{P}^2$, then the normalization function gives $\psi$, but there need not be $\phi$.

Comment: @JasonStarr, why is it true that if X is normal, then those conditions are equivalent?

Comment: @JasonStarr : It is a birational problem, so how can normality be relevant?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: That depends on what the OP means by "$k$-rational map".  When I write that, I mean "rational transformation defined over $k$", rather than "regular morphism defined over $k$".  However, based on the previous post, I suspect the OP wants the morphism to be everywhere regular.

Comment: Sorry. I mean by $\varphi$ and $\psi$ rational dominant maps over $k$, but not regular.

Comment: Then (1) means that the function field $K$ of $X$ is ($k$-isomorphic to) a purely inseparable extension of $k(x,y)$. But then $K\subset k(x^{p^{-m}},y^{p^{-m}})$ for large $m$, which implies (2) since $k(x^{p^{-m}},y^{p^{-m}})$ is $k$-isomorphic to $k(x,y)$. The converse is proved similarly. This works over any perfect $k$.